# Installing Google Cloud Datastore gcd

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to wrap my head around working with Google Cloud Datastore but am having trouble getting started. I've downloaded the zip of the gcd tool (v1beta2) as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/downloads), which, when unpacked, is comprised of three files: gcd.sh, gcd.cmd, and CloudDatastore.jar. Unfortunately, there are no further instructions on what to do next - where to install it, what path variables or permissions to set, etc. Can someone fill me in?

TIA - Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typical usage looks something like:

```
# create a dataset
gcd.sh create my-project

# start the local datastore
gcd.sh start my-project
```

Then, if you're using the Java or Python protocol buffers library, you set a couple of environment variables to instruct the client to use the local datastore:

```
export DATASTORE_HOST=http://localhost:8080
export DATASTORE_DATASET=my-project
```

You can find more details about the `gcd` tool (including instructions for managing indexes) [here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Ed. But I don't get where to copy the gcd.sh files to? User root directory? Bin? Apologies for being so clueless.

Comment: As long as you keep the enclosing directory intact, you can put it wherever you'd like. If it's in your search path, you'll be able to run it as just `gcd.sh`.

Comment: Okay, getting closer. I moved it to the SDK bin folder and when I issue a gcd.sh command, I get this error: "./.appengine/lib/appengine-tools-api.jar not found". Shouldn't that be part of the SDK?

Comment: I did get it to work by unzipping via the command line rather than double-clicking and using the default tool. Not sure why that made a diff, but it worked. Thanks again for your help.